# What's the expected number of pairs to arrange 9 cats and 8 dogs into 17 places on a row?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

What's the expected number of pairs to arrange 9 cats and 8 dogs into 17 places in a row. A pair means a dog sits next to a cat.

My approach is to think it as $$P(X=1) \cdot 1 + P(X=2) \cdot 2 + \cdots + P(X=8) \cdot 8$$ where $X$ is the number of pairs appearing in the row. But this approach requires lots of calculations for $P(X=1)$ to $P(X=8)$ and it is not trivial.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Let $X_i$ be $0$ if position $i$ and $i+1$ have the same type of animal, and $1$ if they are different.  Then $X=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{16},$ then use that expectation is additive.

Comment: Are you familiar with linearity of expectation ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So the answer is simply 0.5*16=8? Is there any reason why $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be viewed as independent events? Thank you

Comment: That would only be true if the probability that seats $i$ and $i+1$ having different animals was $\frac12.$ It isn't. Also, the $X_i$ don't need to be independent to use linearity of expectations. @Pandaaaaaaa $E(X_1+X_2+\cdots)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots$ whether the $X_i$ are independent not.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the linearity and independent! I think I figured it out $E(X_i)=9/17$ when seats $i$ and $i+1$ have different animals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly about defining appropriate indicator variables, simplifying using linearity of expectation and symmetry, then using combinatorial arguments to solve the simplified expression.

Let's define indicator variables: for $i \in \{1,\ldots,16\}$,

- $X_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if there is a dog in seat } i \text{ and a cat in seat } i+1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$
- $Y_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if there is a cat in seat } i \text{ and a dog in seat } i+1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

(It is possible to define the indicator variables differently and still come to the same result.)

So we're after the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value): $$E(X_1 + \cdots + X_{16} + Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{16}).$$

By [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) this is equal to $$E(X_1) + \cdots + E(X_{16}) + E(Y_1) + \cdots + E(Y_{16}).$$

From here,

- we use symmetry to argue that $E(X_1)=\cdots=E(X_{16})=E(Y_1)=\cdots=E(Y_{16})$, which enables us to simplify the expression; and
- we note
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  E(X_1) &= \mathrm{Prob}(\text{there is a dog in seat } 1 \text{ and a cat in seat } 2) \\
  &= \frac{\text{number of arrangements in which there is a dog in seat } 1 \text{ and a cat in seat } 2}{\text{total number of arrangements}}. \\
  \end{align*}
  $$
  and then use combinatorial arguments to find a value of $E(X_1)$.